# Change the layout in flutter listview

Tags: flutter

I recently started building my first flutter application ever and I currently don't like the design I have and want to change it so that the picture displays on the left side of the container and the text right next to it. This will make each container smaller and easier to navigate. But I am stuck on how to do it. I first started of with a gridview and it was displaying correctly but I decided to go with a listview instead which would look better for the purpose of my app.

```
child: ListView.builder( //gridview.builder
          itemCount: pdfData.length,
          //gridDelegate: 
          //SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PdfViewerScreen(pdfUrl: pdfData[index]['url'])),);
                },
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(),
                  ),
                  
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        "lib/images/woolworths.png",
                        height: 120,
                        width: 100,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        pdfData[index]['name'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
```

PS. The text and file are filled from my firebase storage. Which works :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Widget ListTile here.

```
ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset(
                    "lib/images/woolworths.png",
                    height: 120,
                    width: 100,
                  ),
        title: Text(
                    pdfData[index]['name'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
      ),)
```

Entire Code would look like this:

```
child: ListView.builder( //gridview.builder
      itemCount: pdfData.length,
      //gridDelegate: 
      //SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PdfViewerScreen(pdfUrl: pdfData[index]['url'])),);
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(),
              ),
              
              child: ListTile(
             leading: Image.asset(
                    "lib/images/woolworths.png",
                    height: 120,
                    width: 100,
                  ),
              title: Text(
                    pdfData[index]['name'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
               ),
         ),)
            ),
          ),
        );
      },)
```

You can also wrap it in Card widget to Distinguish the tiles from each other.

```
Card( child: ListTile(
        leading: Image.asset(
                    "lib/images/woolworths.png",
                    height: 120,
                    width: 100,
                  ),
        title: Text(
                    pdfData[index]['name'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                   )
                 ,))
```